# What is causing the 2010 bugs?

Tags: y2k

There are a lot of reports of systems failing to understand the year 2010 but I've no idea why. Current systems I look after are working fine as far as I could tell but I'd like to know what the actual problem is to search better.

Could anyone shed some light on it please?

Edit: http://www.rte.ie/business/2010/0105/bug.html - Information about it affecting credit cards in Germany

Comment: Oh dear, that's awfully vague.  Do you have any links to share?

Comment: I heard something about interpreting `10` as hexadecimal number.

Comment: It's just preparation for the 2012 apocalypse.

Comment: Maybe consultants added these bugs back when they fixed Y2K, so they'd have a bunch of easy work to do 10 years later.

Comment: maybe it doesn't fit this site, but an interesting question nontheless.

Comment: Smart move, by jumping from 2009 to 2016 we mis the destruction of the world in 2012. This programmer deserves the nobel peace price!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Several protocols used in banking and telecommunications [- including the SMS protocol](http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/scts.html) - encode the year as [BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) in a single byte.

From 2000-2009 one could easily make the mistake of interpreting the year as a standard binary number since the encoding would be the same:

```
Encoding  Binary-interpreted  BCD-interpreted
0x01      2001                2001
0x02      2002                2002
...
0x09      2009                2009
0x10      2016                2010
...
```

That is most probably the cause of the Windows Mobile bug.

Answer (score 13):

One possible explanation is in the article below

http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/01/05/symantec_y2k10_bug/

> Reminds me of your recent article about cheap and dirty Y2K bug fixes where some unscrupulous programmers put in a simple if <10 = 20xx otherwise the date is 19xx

Comment: Windows, currently, has the same thing. Two-digit years are intrepreted as a date between 1930 and 2029. Which makes the code `if < 30 = 20xx otherwise the date is 19xx`. The fix is to smack people, willingly, using 2-digit years (including end-users)

Answer (score 11):

SpamAssassin had a rule to mark dates too far in the future as spam:

```
/20[1-9][0-9]/
```

The fix came a few days too late, but it's quite simple:

```
/20[2-9][0-9]/
```

See you again in ten years.

Comment: First I though that you must be kidding. But then I checked https://issues.apache.org/SpamAssassin/show_bug.cgi?id=6269. Doesn't seem too hard for me to compare two 4-digit integers with each other. Why do they use regular expressions for that?

Comment: Because everybody knows that, if you can't express it in a Regex, it's just not worth doing...  ;)

Comment: May be to avoid string to integer conversions?

Comment: Why not just sample the system date, and base the "too far in the future" off of that?  WTF?

Answer (score 4):

I've got a system at work that uses a one digit year field.   Yes.  One digit.  So the reason this system is failing is that "2000" is expressed the same as "2010".

Comment: Is/was there any kind of rationale for that decision?

Comment: I have no idea, and no real way of finding out.

Comment: "We'll never be using this software 10 year from now."

Comment: Some versions of the TRS-80 DOS (like TRSDOS 6) used one octal digit (three bits) to represent the year.  That was one of the things pushing me to get off the TRS-80 Model 4 and onto a Macintosh.

Comment: The AT&T 6300 had the same problem: The internal clock could only represent years between 1984 and 1991.

Answer (score 4):

The one I heard about was quick fixes people did for Y2K without thinking it through. So if xx < 10 then 20xx else 19xx.

Comment: Doesn't really exaplain the 16

Comment: Where's 16 come from? Question just asks about systems failing to understand 2010. 0x10=16 could be one reason, sure.

Comment: The 2010 to 2016 bug may not be the only bug here... This could very well explain the problem the German banks are having.

Answer (score 4):

It might be due to the young developers who started their careers after Y2K and are using 1 digit to represent the year.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more characteristic of an older developer who has more experience (a) minimizing these representations and (b) developing the systems where this is more likely to happen?

Comment: Or it might be the Y2K consultants who didn't make enough to retire :)

Answer (score 4):

I took care of a little 2010 fail in a site last weekend, it was just the result of an oversight in coding though.

Someone thought it would be a good idea to set the value of a list item to the current dateTime.year.Now() when the list only contained items up to 2009.

```
ddlItem.findByText(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a screen shot of the norton symantec endpoint protection

[alt text http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/4500/152010112800am.jpg](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/4500/152010112800am.jpg)

Really nice that no one @ symantec informed their customers...
Till the article was posted: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/01/05/symantec_y2k10_bug/

Answer (score 2):

It is that there is a bug in a component that splits the year in two parts. The second part is used in a comparison so that the digit 10 is not in base 10, it's in base 16 meaning that it's 0x10 = 16 (hex).

Answer (score 2):

I used Google Code Search to [find y2010 bugs in open source software](http://ghewgill.livejournal.com/140515.html). I looked for one particular pattern that would indicate a bug (use of "200%d" as a printf format string), and found several projects with that bug. Creative application of search patterns could probably turn up more different kinds of bugs.